# How do I stop spaces appearing in this program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In class im meant to write a program that arranges coordinates for you. I wrote this:

```
x = input("")
y = input("")
z = input("")

print("(",x,",",y,",",z,")\n)
```

and the output is: (␣0␣,␣-7831␣,␣2323␣)⤶
how do I stop the extra spaces from appearing so I get this?: (0,␣-7831,␣2323)⤶

Comment: What are the `␣,␣` charecters? Artifacts from copying from the terminal?

Comment: they are spaces. The website that im using to submit the work adds spaces like that so you can see how many there are. The commas are meant to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern Python, the nicest way is to use an f-string:

```
print(f"({x},{y},{z})")
```

Note how the string is prefixed with `f`. Everything between the curly braces `{}` then gets interpreted as a Python expression which is subsequently converted to a string and inserted at that point.

Note that `print` already follows up with a newline, so unless you want an extra one (that is, a blank line), you don't need to add `\n` yourself.